# Bug when trying to add relocation country

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, user-interface

On [carrers.stackoverflow.com](http://carrers.stackoverflow.com), when editing my profile, I'm experiencing this strange bug when trying to add a country to which I am willing to relocate.

**Steps to reproduce the issue**

1. Go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit.
2. Click on the second `edit` button from the top.
3. Check `I’m willing to relocate`.
4. Click `add location`.
5. Enter `Neverland` in the field.
6. Click on `add location` again to add another location.
7. The glitch shows up.

**The screenshot**

> [image: Glitch screenshot]

Has anyone else experienced this glitch?

Comment: The feedback text has fairy dust sprinkled on it, and is happily trying to fly away!

Comment: I certainly can reproduce this as well; the labels on the left-hand side no longer *stay* to the left when the error message is given, breaking the whole layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks better now? [image]